# Amazon RDS (CLI) - Restore instance from snapshot - wrong security group (No inbound permissions)

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, restore, snapshot, rds

I'm preparing a small bash script that reads the latest snapshot name for a given instance and creates an new instance from that snapshot. The command I'm using is

```
rds-restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot snapshot-instance --db-snapshot-identifier rds:snapshot-name --region eu-west-1 --availability-zone eu-west-1a --db-instance-class db.t2.micro --multi-az false
```

This is working fine, the instance gets created. But the instance has wrong security group assignments, preventing it from being accessed from outside (which is needed for a standard "dumping" of the sql-data).

The original Security Group (VPC) of the snapshott'ed instance was

```
default (sg-2bc44xxx) ( active )
```

but when the new instance from the snapshot is created via CLI, it gets the following assignments:

```
default:vpc-95c10xxx ( active )
rds-default-vpc-95c10-xxxx (sg-9e45bxxx) ( active )
```

You see the difference of the Security group (sg) of the old security group and the new one.

But I cannot change this connection via CLI:

```
rds-modify-db-instance snapshot-instance --region eu-west-1 -sg sg-2bc44xxx
```

Result in

```
"Malformed input-MalformedInput".
```

Other try:

```
rds-modify-db-instance snapshot-instance --region eu-west-1 -a sg-2bc44xxx
```

which gives

```
Could not find the resource you requested: DBSecurityGroup not found:  sg-2bc44xxx
```

When I change the group via Web-Console to the default one, the inbound connection is usable and I can take a mysqldump without any problem.

Currently it is unclear what option to use, either -a or -sg. Also, it is unclear what the correct identifier for security groups is (id, group-name, ...).

Any help or information would be highly appreciated.

Regards,

Erik

Comment: to find out more about your security groups you can run `rds-describe-db-security-groups` - it also looks like `-a` is used for your DB security groups and `-sg` for the VPC. did you try `--vpc-security-group-ids sg-2bc44xxx`

Comment: One thing I don't understand is why the newly created instances are bound to security groups for DB and VPC separately, whereas the origin instance(s) have only the VPC connection.

The outputs of my attempts are:

    rds-modify-db-instance snapper-1 --region eu-west-1 --vpc-security-group-ids sg-2bc44xxx => unrecognized option (although its documented)

rds-modify-db-instance snapper-1 --region eu-west-1 -sg sg-2bc44xxx => Malformed input-MalformedInput

----------
rds-modify-db-instance snapper-1 --region eu-west-1 --db-security-groups default => "SC does not belong to VPC vpc-95c10xxx"

Comment: Add --db-subnet-group-name <subnet group name> to your command line.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue, so after restoring the database using a snapshot, I see that the security group assigned is default, which does not have any inbound rules. 
If you go to the home page of your RDS console, you can see the configuration for supported platforms as either (EC2, VPC) or just (VPC) as shown [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithSecurityGroups.html)

Sadly, restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot was not taking in any vpc-security groups option. So after restoring the database, I had to modify it using

```
aws rds modify-db-instance --db-instance-identifier your-db-identifier --vpc-security-group-ids sg-4xxxxxxx
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I came back here to inform that I ran with a different solution. I used the AWS SDK for PHP and was able to easily get the name of latest snapshot via API. I used it then to spin up a temp-instance (which is bound to the same security groups, paramater groups etc. like the original instance), poll this instance until it's in state "ready" and then perform an actual mysqldump which is then uploaded to S3. After that, I destroy the temp-instance. It's all done via a PHP shell-script and the usage of the official AWS SDK for PHP.

The script is working fine without any errors for nearly 2 years now every day (the dumps are ~ 15GB in size). Thanks anyway for your answers, they might be helpful for others that come across this issue. It's really easy to accomplish these things with the SDK.